# Kafka Customer Thread,Task,Partition?

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, consumer

I have a kafka cluster which has 3 machines. And a topic which has 6 partitions(2 partitions every machine). 
When i start a consumer application which has 6 consumer threads and belong to one group. I know one consumer thread will be assigned one partition. 
What i want to know is: The task of the consumer thread will be runned on the machine where the partition on? Or will be runned on the machine where the app be srarted?

Answer (score 1):

The model your are talking about sounds like the one we have with Apache Spark where workers for processing data run on worker nodes coordinated by a driver application on a the developer/user machine.
Kafka doesn't work in this way.
Kafka brokers are independent from the Kafka application(s) where consumers run for getting messages from topics/partitions.
Where you start your consumer application(s) that is the machine where the application runs; it doesn't run on the broker nodes. The application with related consumers will connect to the "remote" broker nodes for getting messages.
It's also true that you can just run your Kafka application(s) on a broker node just as another JVM process but it's not the model you describe above (as I said is much more like Apache Spark)